# How to make a site have a built in user-friendly editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor

So, I created a site for a friend, and am giving it to him. He doesn't know HTML/CSS/JavaScript very well, that's why he asked me to create it.

He didn't want to use a web creator, he wanted entirely his own setup.

Only problem is now he needs to be able to edit it. How can I add one of those fancy editors into the site for him? Is it possible? Is there one already created for import?

**Edit for aditional clarity**

Somethink like one of the editors you might see on a site like Weebly.

**[end edit]**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an easy way to do this. You could integrate some kind of control panel with PHP and SQL, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried about this. Oh well.